# Extract specific image url from HTML source code with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, get

I managed to extract the source code of a website, and now I need to find the URL to a specific image in the source. The source I retrieved is in a string format, stored in $query.

The format the image comes in is as follows:

```
<img src="#####500x500.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="#####" itemprop="#####">
```

The ##### means that part of the code is different per URL I use. If I open the source code of the page in my web browser (Chrome: right click, view page source) and I search for 500x500 myself, I get 2 results. The second result is the image I'm looking for, and I want to grab the src attribute of that image.

So as an example:
I enter a URL, the code I already have gets the source in a string format, and somewhere inside that string is the following:

```
<img src="https://example.com/hello500x500.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="random-alt" itemprop="random-prop">
```

Now I want to store the src attribute in a variable.

Basically, in the end I get the following variable:

```
$variablename = 'https://example.com/hello500x500.jpg';
```

Comment: You can try to use preg_match or xpath

Comment: Did you try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regexp for that, try something like

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<img src=(\'|")(.*500x500\.jpg)/i', $content, $m);
```

The matches are stored in `$m`, use `var_dump($m)` to inspect the contents

Comment: I found a solution already, but thank you for the help